# How do I schedule a task to happen every 'N' seconds in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

How do I wire up my web.xml to have a task happen every n many seconds. Moreover, I need to have a server method refresh every 5 seconds via a method call.

Much thanks in advance

SOLVED:

http://javaprogrammingtips4u.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-implement-task-scheduler-job.html

Comment: Do you want your view page to be refreshed every 5 seconds or you just want some actions to be done on server every 5 seconds without showing it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can annotate the desired routine using

```
public class Foo {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    public void Bar() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

But in order to for Spring for find and recognize the annotation you must declare which base package the class `Foo` lies in as well as configure Spring to look for scheduling tasks. Put the following in your spring XML configuration (and don't forget to import the XML namespaces `context`and `task`).

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.scheduling"/>
<task:annotation-driven />
```

Alternatively you can put @EnableScheduling before the class declaration and it does the XML config for you out of the box.

See also [the *context* namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context) and [the *task* namespace](http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd).

Comment: Not clear.  How is the XML annotation tied to the method? class? you are scheduling.

Comment: Please clarify how i use the <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.scheduling"/>
<task:annotation-driven /> in regards to the Foo class above

Comment: @Jammin, just make sure the class lies in the java package identifier by the component-scan tag. The task tag is springs way of enabling annotation driven scheduling.

Comment: @Jammin, yes see [the context schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context) documentation for a sample.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Quartz scheduler integration as documented here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/scheduling.html

I do not understand the 2nd part of your question about refreshing a server method.

Answer (score 2):

How abt using Quartz with spring. This is highly configurable by spliting Jobs, triggers and timers up. You can also use cron expressions and integrate things like JMX:

[Spring and Quartz](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Spring manual, section 25, [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).  When I've done this sort of thing I used annotations, described in [section 25.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support).  In short, in a Spring-managed bean you annotate the method you want to run with `@Scheduled` and add a couple of lines to your applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 1):

This expression will run every 5 seconds in working days:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
    public void updateAllStatements() {
...........
}
```

To check cron expression I'm using this method:

```
/**
     * Checks provided Cron expression
     *
     * @param cronExpression
     */
    public static void checkCronExpression(final String cronExpression) {
        try {
            Date now = new Date();

            System.out.println(now);

            final CronSequenceGenerator gen = new CronSequenceGenerator(cronExpression);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                now = gen.next(now);

                System.out.println(now);
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```